# Reactjs counter onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter

Using MUI Boxes i am trying to display a counter variable which gets incremented everytime one of [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcm2e.png) cells is clicked.I tried adding a counter as a state of a cell which gets incremented whenever the color of each Cell component is changed (everytime a cell is clicked) but doesn't seem to be working.

```js
  
// =====================================================================================================================
//  C O M P O N E N T
// =====================================================================================================================

class Cell extends React.Component {
    state = {
        color: '#bbdefb',
        count: 0,
    };

    onChange = () => {
        this.setState({color: 'red'});
        this.setState({count: count++});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: this.state.color,
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    opacity: '60%',
                    outlineStyle: 'solid',
                    outlineWidth: '1px',
                    outlineColor: '#1a237e',
                }}
                onClick={this.onChange}
            />
        );
    }
}

class Main extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Box sx={SX.root}>
                <Box sx={SX.page}>
                    <MathGrid sx={SX.math1} />
                    <Box sx={SX.firstrow}>
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={SX.secondrow}>
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={SX.thirdrow}>
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={SX.forthrow}>
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                        <Cell />
                    </Box>
                </Box>
                <Box sx={SX.header} />
                <Box sx={SX.footer}>
                    <Box sx={SX.counter}>{count}</Box>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        );
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  I N T E R N A L
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}

// =====================================================================================================================
//  E X P O R T
// =====================================================================================================================
export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 things :

- If you define your count on the individual Cell component you have one count  by component Cell (so if you want on count for the group, you need to  create a count directly on Main
  _ You use count on Main component but where is from, how you take it ?
  _ after setState the component directly re-render so you never past by your second setState (your update color, not your count)
- for update count on setState, you need to call this.state.count, count is not define
- you can't use this.state.count++ because it's mutable but you can use this.state.count + 1

Try cell like this and see the comportement with comment different setState :

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
  state = {
    color: "#bbdefb",
    count: 0,
  };

  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({ color: "red" });
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count++ });
    // this.setState({ color: "red", count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: this.state.color,
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          opacity: "60%",
          outlineStyle: "solid",
          outlineWidth: "1px",
          outlineColor: "#1a237e",
        }}
        onClick={this.onChange}
      >
        {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Tried this, but unfortunately it would display a number in every cell. I need that variable to be displayed at the bottom of the screen,somewhere inside footer. Also, if you click twice on the same cell it would count 2, i need to count just +1

Comment: You need create the count and setCount on the Main component. I’m not on my office, I show you later the idea if you want

Answer (score 0):

So :

- if you want 1 counter for all, you need to put the count on the Main Component
- if you want count just one, is not a addition but just an assignment (value = 1) or you need to create a verification for know if your element need to be increment again
- if your create every time the same element (4 box with for each inside 9 cells), take time to see render by iteration on array (turfu)
- take time to compare your solution with this and it's more efficient if you take time to write more than copy/past
- read the doc of React class component

  class Cell extends React.Component {
  state = {
  color: "#bbdefb",
  isChecked: false,
  };

  ```
  onChange = () => {
    if (!this.state.isChecked) {
      this.props.addCount();
      this.setState({ color: "red", isChecked: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: this.state.color,
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          opacity: "60%",
          outlineStyle: "solid",
          outlineWidth: "1px",
          outlineColor: "#1a237e",
        }}
        onClick={this.onChange}
      >
        {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
  ```

  }

  class Main extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
  count: 0,
  };

  ```
  addToCount = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Box>
        <Box>
          <Box>
            <Cell addCount={this.addToCount} />
            <Cell addCount={this.addToCount} />
          </Box>
        </Box>
        <Box />
        <Box>
          <Box>{this.state.count}</Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    );
  }
  ```

  export default Main;

Say me if it's ok and if you understand what everything is.